# How to create an Aurora replica of a PostgreSQL RDS database using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I've been tasked with updating our Postgres database to Aurora Postgres, and the first step is throwing me off. We use Terraform to manage our infrastructure, have a primary and a single replica of the database. So far, I've run into many problems using Terraform to do what is really easy in the console.

Desired outcome: run `terraform apply` and have a freshly created Aurora Postgres replica show up and be readable by our applications.

Code (I left a bunch of potentially useless info, but wanted to make it as easy as possible to understand):

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "rds_postgres" {
  identifier                   = "postgres-database"
  allocated_storage            = "250"
  engine                       = "postgres"
  engine_version               = "11.6"
  instance_class               = "db.t3.large"
  name                         = "prod_db"
  username                     = "admin"
  password                     = "p@ssw0rd"
  db_subnet_group_name         = "subnet-group-name"
  vpc_security_group_ids       = ["sg-xxxxxxx"]
  storage_encrypted            = true
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "rds_postgres_r1" {
  identifier                   = "postgres-database-r1"
  allocated_storage            = "250"
  engine                       = "postgres"
  engine_version               = "11.6"
  instance_class               = "db.t3.large"
  name                         = "prod_db"
  username                     = "admin"
  vpc_security_group_ids       = ["sg-xxxxxxx"]
  replicate_source_db          = "${aws_db_instance.rds_postgres.identifier}"
  storage_encrypted            = true
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster" "default" {
  cluster_identifier            = "postgres-aurora-cluster"
  database_name                 = "prod_db"
  master_username               = "admin"
  master_password               = "p@ssw0rd"
  storage_encrypted             = true
  kms_key_id                    = "alias/kms/rds"
  vpc_security_group_ids        = ["sg-xxxxxxx"]
  db_subnet_group_name          = "subnet-group-name"
  engine                        = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_version                = "11.6"
  replication_source_identifier = "${aws_db_instance.rds_postgres.arn}"

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      "id",
      "kms_key_id",
      "cluster_identifier"
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "default" {
  identifier                      = "postgres-aurora-1"
  cluster_identifier              = "${aws_rds_cluster.default.id}"
  instance_class                  = "db.t3.large"
  db_subnet_group_name            = "subnet-group-name"
  publicly_accessible             = false
  engine                          = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_version                  = "11.6"

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      "identifier",
      "cluster_identifier"
    ]
  }
}
```

Terraform apply will faithfully create a new cluster and single instance initially labeled as a Reader class, and replicate data. However, after the replication is complete, the new aurora instance swaps to Writer.

What am I doing wrong? My next steps are promoting this new Aurora cluster to the primary DB, scaling up readers, and cutting the original Postgres primary out completely, but I am blocked. I'm not a Terraform wizard.